# How to add a key to an associative array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, key, associative-array

What i want:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 154
            [url] => http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8187/8105302152_c886bc2179_c.jpg
            [categorie_id] => 2
            [user_id] => 23
            [time] => 2012-10-20 18:13:40
        )
)
```

What i have:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 158
    [url] => http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8468/8105709759_915c1092b4_c.jpg
    [categorie_id] => 2
    [user_id] => 23
    [time] => 2012-10-20 19:30:16
)
```

(don't mind about the values, they are different and i know that)

Actually quite a simple question, but i just can't find it how to solve it.
Both arrays are associative fetched (this is a return of database).

In the above example there are multiple records (pictures) so it returns a 0,1,2,3, ... and in there the data. When i only have 1 picture in my database i get errors, because i don't have the numeral key ('0') in that array. So i want to add the '0' key.

Comment: `$outerArray = array( $originalArray );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this

```
$oldArray = Array ( [id] => 158 [url] => http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8468/8105709759_915c1092b4_c.jpg [categorie_id] => 2 [user_id] => 23 [time] => 2012-10-20 19:30:16 );

$newArray = array();
$newArray[] = $oldArray;
```

or

```
$newArray[0] = $oldArray;
```

Answer (score 4):

So you're just looking to nest the existing array one level in.  Best way is to just append it onto a new array:

```
$original_array = array('id'=>158, 'url'=>'http:....','categorie_id' => 2, 'user_id' => 23, 'time' => '2012-10-20');

// New array to hold the result
$output = array();
// Append the old array onto the new one with []
$output[] = $original_array;
print_r($output);
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 158
            [url] => http:....
            [categorie_id] => 2
            [user_id] => 23
            [time] => 2012-10-20
        )

)
```

If you *must* specify the key in the outer array, you can do that as well:

```
// Make sure it is at key 1
$output[1] = $original_array;
```

Comment: This works indeed. I'm a bit ashamed now i've asked this question. ^^ But yes, it works fine now. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if I'm reading your question correctly, but it sounds like you just want this:

```
$parent_arr = array ();
$sub_arr = array (
    'id' => 158,
    'url' => '/*url*/',
    'categorie_id' => 2,
    'user_id' => 23,
    'time' => '2012-10-20 19:30:16');

$parent_arr[0] = $sub_arr;
```

Does that answer your question, or am I totally missing what you're asking?

As you likely know, you can assign a new array key in one of three ways:

1. Manually set the key as I did in the example above: `$parent_arr[0]`;
2. Let PHP choose the next available array key: `$parent_arr[]`
3. Use a function like [array_push](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) or [array_unshift](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) to add a new item to the beginning or end of an array.

All of this stuff is covered in the [Arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.array.php) section of the PHP manual.